# Different Browsers are displaying HTML differently

Tags: html, css, vb.net, browser, cross-browser

I am working on some HTML code, its really old code so its not something I am really used to seeing. I made a small change to the code, moved the save button, but when I display it in each of the browsers im testing on, Firefox,Chrome,IE they all look different. Firefox is displaying it the way I want it to [image]

But the other two are displaying the same page, with the same exact code incorrectly. IE [image]

Chrome[image]

Here is my code, please let me know what has gone wrong im not sure how to fix this is issue. Thanks!

```
    <div id="textdefaults" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitTextDefaults" Text="Save" runat="server" Height="29px" style="margin-left: 900px" Width="64px" OnClick="btnSubmitTextDefaults_Click" OnClientClick="SaveLanguage();" />
    </div>
    <div class="aTab">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTextDefaults" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="aTab">
                <TagUpdate:TextDefaults id="myTextDefaults" runat="Server" />
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress3" runat="server">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <div class="progress">
                            <asp:Image ID="imgTextDefaults" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Bannerlink/Images/ajax-loader-big.gif" />Saving...
                            </div>
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmitTextDefaults" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
   <br />
</div>
```

Comment: You may be using the float - have not canceled its action?

Comment: Hey Dmitriy, I dont have any floats except in the css file. I tried changing them but no luck. still the same problem.

Comment: The code looks OK; that won't be the problem. I assume the webpage has a proper DOCTYPE? It's probably the CSS; show us.

Comment: Hey Mr.Lister: here is the CSS code, specifically this is what I want the other things to be contained in. #ContainerContent { width:992px; text-align:left; clear:both; /* margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; */ }

Comment: @vmedhe2 That's not enough; for one thing it doesn't contain the background color that is the most visible part of the issue. Could you make a small demo webpage somewhere? I mean as small as possible but still showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what is happening is the parent div does not wrapped up till the last element.

Make the parent div style below,

```
#ContainerContent { 
   width: 992px; 
   text-align: left; 
   clear: both; 
   /* margin-left:auto; 
   margin-right:auto; */
   display: inline-block;  
}
```

and add a div mentioned below as the last element inside the '#ContainerContent' div.

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

This div wrap up the parent element till the last element exists and the style will be get corrected for all browsers.